# Custom Movable Horizontal Line in jQuery Flot Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I created a line chart with Flot. The Y scale reaches for example from 0 - 100. Now I have an input field where a user can enter a number from 0-100.

If he choses, lets say 80, I want to create a horizontal line on the chart at Y=80 indicating the selected value. This line should be adjustable at any time.

I haven't found anything so far but I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [markings](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) option to read the value from the input and redraw your chart when the input value changes, something like this:

```
var yvalue = parseInt( $('#yvalue').val());
plot.getOptions().grid.markings = [ { yaxis: { from: yvalue, to: yvalue}, color: "#0000bb" } ];
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foa6fzy2/) with a similar example.